# YOLOV1 theory of 2 bounding box predictors in each grid cell and its possible power as psuedo anchor boxes

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, grid, anchor, yolo

After YOLO1 there was a trend of using anchor boxes for a while in other iterations as priors (I believe the reason was to both speed up the training and detect different sized objects better)

However YOLOV1 has an interesting mechanism where there are k number of bounding box predictors sliding each grid cell in order to be able to specialize in detecting different scaled objects.

Here is what I wonder, ladies and gentlemen:

Given a very long training time, can these bounding box predictors in YOLOV1 achieve better bounding boxes compared to YOLOV9000 or its counterparts that rely on anchor box mechanism

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, yes they can. I observed two possible optimization paths, one of which is already implemented in latest version of YOLOV3 and V5 by Ultralytics (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5)

1. What I observed was that for a YOLOv3, even before training, using a K means clustering we can ascertain a number of ``common box'' shapes. These data when fed into the network as anchor maskes really improved the performance of the YOLOv3 network for "that particular" dataset since the non-max suppression routine had much better chance of succeeding at filtering out spurious detection for particular classes in each of the detection head. To the best of my knowledge, this technique was implemented in latest iterations of their bounding box regression code.
2. Suppressing certain layers. In YOLOv3, the network performed detection in three stages with the idea of progressively detecting larger objects to smaller objects. YOLOv3 (and in theory V1) can benefit if with some trial and error, you can ascertain which detection head is your network preferring to use based on the common bounding box shapes that you found in step 1.